# AWS EMR Hue S3 File Browser not able to access AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, hue

I have an EMR with Huw application and LDAP authentication.\n

i am following http://gethue.com/introducing-s3-support-in-hue/

i have setup ldap user aws profile and seeded hue.ini with aws key.

My ldap user is able to access s3 from EMR CLI using aws CLI .

i am using same ldap user to login into hue but hue s3 file browser is giving below error

```
Processing exception: S3 filesystem exception.: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.7.egg/django/db/transaction.py", line 371, in inner
    return func(*args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/apps/filebrowser/src/filebrowser/views.py", line 214, in view
    raise PopupException(msg, detail=e)
PopupException: S3 filesystem exception.
**exceptions_renderable ERROR    Potential detail: Access Denied**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved now

Version details are AWS EMR-5.7.0 , Hue 3.12.0.

emr-5.7.0 takes care of integrating of Hue with S3.
S3 browser works given LDAP user, used in hue should should have permissions on bucket.

**Problem in our case was that EMR was in a private VPC and when we opened up VPC endpoint policy to allow "s3:ListAllMyBuckets" for whole s3 for everyone, which hue s3 browser does it started working..**

No change in hue.ini was required , No aws api Keys Needed , only VPC policy change fixed the issue.